# Hadoop error in shuffle in fetcher: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop. I have a kerberos security enabled hadoop cluster (master and 1 slave) set up on a virtual box. I am trying to run a job from the hadoop examples 'pi'. The job terminates with the error Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES. I tried searching for this error but the solutions given on the internet do not seem to be working for me. Perhaps I am missing something obvious. I even tried removing the slave from the etc/hadoop/slaves file to see if the job can run only on the master but that fails as well with the same error. Below is the log. I am running this on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 virtual box. Any help appreciated.

```
montauk@montauk-vmaster:/usr/local/hadoop$ sudo -u yarn bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.0.jar pi 2 10
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 10
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/06/05 12:04:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Starting Job
14/06/05 12:04:49 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /192.168.0.29:8040
14/06/05 12:04:50 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Created HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 17 for yarn on 192.168.0.29:54310
14/06/05 12:04:50 INFO security.TokenCache: Got dt for hdfs://192.168.0.29:54310; Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 192.168.0.29:54310, Ident: (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 17 for yarn)
14/06/05 12:04:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
14/06/05 12:04:51 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
14/06/05 12:04:51 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1401975262053_0007
14/06/05 12:04:51 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 192.168.0.29:54310, Ident: (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 17 for yarn)
14/06/05 12:04:53 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1401975262053_0007
14/06/05 12:04:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://montauk-vmaster:8088/proxy/application_1401975262053_0007/
14/06/05 12:04:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1401975262053_0007
14/06/05 12:05:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1401975262053_0007 running in uber mode : false
14/06/05 12:05:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/06/05 12:06:04 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
14/06/05 12:06:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/06/05 12:06:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/06/05 12:06:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1401975262053_0007_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in fetcher#4
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.ShuffleSchedulerImpl.checkReducerHealth(ShuffleSchedulerImpl.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.ShuffleSchedulerImpl.copyFailed(ShuffleSchedulerImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyFromHost(Fetcher.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:165)
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem as yours when I install cdh5.1.0 with kerberos security using tarball,solutions found by google are insufficient memory,but I don't think it's my situation since my input is very small (52K).

After digging several days,I found root cause in [this link](https://www.mail-archive.com/yarn-dev@hadoop.apache.org/msg06913.html).

To sum up solutions in that link can be:

1. add following property in yarn-site.xml even it's default in yarn-default.xml

   `<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
   </property>`
2. remove property **yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs** and use default value /tmp.Then exec following commands:

   `mkdir -p /tmp/hadoop-yarn/nm-local-dir
   chown yarn:yarn /tmp/hadoop-yarn/nm-local-dir`

The problem can be concluded:

After setting  **yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs property**, the property **yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class** in yarn-default.xml doesn't work.

The root cause I haven't found also.

Comment: FYI yarn-site.xml is located here `/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml` usually but for me on AWS EMR it is located here `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml` which is a symlink to the actual location of `/etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf/yarn-site.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.I had mapreduce job without reducer.Then I solved it using `job.setNumReduceTasks(0);`

Comment: Where does this line go? I'm not sure what to do with `job.setNumReduceTasks(0);`

Answer (score 0):

1. change below property in yarn-site.xml and create the directory.

   yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs
       /tmp

   mkdir -p /tmp/hadoop-yarn/nm-local-dir
   chown yarn:yarn /tmp/hadoop-yarn/nm-local-dir
2. tune the resources properety in mapred-site.xml

   mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent=0.50
   mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent=0.2
   mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies=4
3. Restart resourcemanager and nodemanager on their respective nodes.